# Does Flutter StreamBuilder work for widgets further down the widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I have placed the streambuilder at the top of the widget tree to listen to a stream. If the stream has data and the data contains A, it will return Apage() as shown in the picture. From Apage(), I can push to DPage().

If I were to delete the data from DPage, would the stream builder automatically return cPage(), or do I have to use Navigator.pop(context) to return to the Home page?

If I were to edit the data from DPage and change it to B, would the stream builder automatically return BPage(), or do I have to use Navigator.pop(context) to return to the Home page?

[image]

Comment: if you do `Navigator.push` then you always have to `Navigator.pop` in order to return to parent page

Comment: I see, so that means I would need to run Navigator.pop together with changing of data in Dpage to move to BPage. Okay got it, I'll try that out. Thanks!

Comment: no there is no need to push or pop.... let get you a sample code...

Comment: update the question with a sample home code....

Answer (score 0):

Just a sample code... with this you will understand how you can use it with widget and return whatever you want

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp()
      .then((value) => print("connected " + value.options.asMap.toString()))
      .catchError(
        (e) => print(
          e.toString(),
        ),
      );
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);
  SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool security1 = pref.getBool('security') ?? false;
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (BuildContext context) => ThemeProvider(),
      child: streamBuilder(
stream:// your query....
builder:(context, snapshot){
if(snapshot.hasdata){
return MyApp(
        security: security1,
      ),
    ),
}
if (!snapshot.hasdata){
return Center(child: CicularProgressIndicator();
}
return HomeScreen()
}
)

  );
}
```

Comment: hmmm, whenever snapshot has data, you seemed to return 2 widget(myApp and LockScreen). Why do you do that though?

Comment: For example, if you were to return MyApp, and you push to another page to delete the data, do you still need to pop for the streambuilder to work and return you the homescreen?

Comment: sorry it was a mistake(!snapshot.hasdata) that is what i am suppose to put there

Comment: For example, if you were to return MyApp, and you push to another page to delete the data, do you still need to pop for the streambuilder to work and return you the homescreen? ....... No, you can learn about streambuilder very well. stream upade automatically.

Comment: that code is just a sample code, let me update it